# Can I send slack chats directly from Azure Devops after installing slack integration?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, slack

Is there a possibility to send slack chat to individuals directly from Azure DevOps tool? I have done the slack integration with Azure DevOps service hooks.

I have also tried to install Slack Notification from Azure DevOps marketplace.

Comment: Are you referring to sending Azure DevOps notifications to specific users rather than a channel?

Comment: Kind of. I was hopping i can click on the avatar in DevOps to trigger slack chat rather than skype.